# Java generic wildcard bounded in lists

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand Java Generics and I'm puzzled by the bounded wildcards. I'm using the hierarchy from the [Guidelines for Wildcard Use](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html) and have added a class PositiveEvenNumber inheriting from EvenNumber.

```
    List<? super EvenNumber> xn = new ArrayList<NaturalNumber>();
    xn.add(new NaturalNumber(35));  // compile-time error
    xn.add(new EvenNumber(-70));
    xn.add(new PositiveEvenNumber(70));
    xn.add(new Object());  // compile-time error
```

Why does the first line compile ? On second line, isn't NaturalNumber a parent of EvenNumber, why can't it be added ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `List<? super EvenNumber>` is a list of some *specific* type, provided that that type is a supertype of `EvenNumber`.

Therefore, it might be a `List<EvenNumber>`, in which case you can't add a `NaturalNumber`.

This also means that you can't read anything from the list (except as `Object`), since you don't know what type the list actually contains.  (it could even be a `List<Object>`)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but NaturalNumber is a supertype of EvenNumber. Why doesn't it stop there (plus it was instantiated with ArrayList<NaturalNumber>)?

Comment: @Fram: Because it can also be a `List<EvenNumber>` itself, which a `NaturalNumber` isn't.  And, the expression you assign it to has no effect on the (compile-time) type of the variable.  If you want a `List<NaturalNumber>`, you should declare a `List<NaturalNumber>`.